# Why this throws error when I user filter in django

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm tried this
print(request.user.profile.messages.filter(is_read=True).count())
and this

print(Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user.profile,is_read=False))

this is showing this error

djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

```
    Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT "users_message"."sender_id", "users_message"."recipient_id", "users_message"."sender_name", "users_message"."email", "users_message"."subject", "users_message"."body", "users_message"."is_read", "users_message"."msg_read", "users_message"."created", "users_message"."id" FROM "users_message" WHERE (NOT "users_message"."is_read" AND "users_message"."recipient_id" = %(0)s) ORDER BY "users_message"."is_read" ASC, "users_message"."created" DESC LIMIT 21
```

Params: (UUID('c7a7c847-cd94-419d-a86c-f8935a2abd80'),)
Version: 1.3.6
Sub SQL: None
FAILED SQL: None
Params: None
Version: None

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

https://pastebin.com/SPfYPW8E

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=400,blank=False,null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='profiles/',default="profiles/user-default.png")
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)



class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True,related_name="messages")
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)
    msg_read = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)

#views.py file
def profiles(request):
    profiles, search_query = searchProfiles(request)
    custom_paginator, profiles = paginateProfiles(request,profiles,6)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            new_msg_count = request.user.profile.messages.all().filter(is_read=True).count()
        except:
            new_msg_count = ""
            print(request.user.profile.messages.filter(is_read=True).count())
            # print(Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user.profile,is_read=False))
            context = {"profiles":profiles, "search_query":search_query, 'custom_paginator':custom_paginator,'unreadCount':new_msg_count}
    context = {"profiles":profiles, "search_query":search_query, 'custom_paginator':custom_paginator}
    return render(request,'users/profiles.html',context)


#setting.py file
mongoDB = True

if mongoDB:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'devsearch',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA':False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': f'mongodb+srv://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@devsearch.{ATLAS_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
            }
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the _full_ traceback you see?

Comment: @sytech hi I added pastebin link.

Comment: Please don't post links to important information. Instead, include the relevant parts of the information directly in your question. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Posts in which information is only present in links are likely to be closed as lacking enough details, as they can become invalid if the linked page changes.